# How do you hide a line in Dynamic AX reports?

Tags: axapta

In body of section I have 4 calculated fields. I want to hide a line when all four fields are 0 value. Please let me know your suggestions...

Answer (score 3):

Create an executeSection method in the body and only call `super()` if you want the section to print:

```
public void executeSection()
{
    if(value1!=0 || value2!=0 || value3!=0 || value4!=0)
    {
        super();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In order of simplicity, you could:

1. Add a range to the query (may not be possible in your case)
2. Add the test in the `executeSection` method of the report section
3. Add the test in the `send` method of the report

Example of an override the `send` method of the report (in this case option 1 would be better):

```
boolean send(Common cursor, int level=1, boolean triggerOffBody=TRUE)
{
    boolean ret;
    InventTable inventTable;

    if (cursor.tableId == TableNum(InventTable))
    {
        inventTable = cursor;
        if (inventTable.InventType == InventType::BOM)
            ret = super(cursor, level, triggerOffBody);
    }

    return ret;
}
```